# Is it possible to get different instances of ejb when using lookup?

Tags: spring, ejb, javabeans

Is it possible to get different instances of ejb when using lookup? I have a JNDI lookup in some wildfly web server which looks for ejb in another wildfly web server (remote ejb) I have stateless ejbs in this server, I kind of need to get "a new" ejb every time I lookup for it.

I know it sounds crazy and probably this is the worst approach possible but this is how the system is: 1 web server holding spring's Bean those lookup for an ejb, this spring beans are session scoped because this is an web application, so every user that log in has a bean to work with, the problem is when they need to lookup for 1 ejb, they lookup for the exact same ejb and I think this could be an issue because this ejb returns some data and this data could be for one user but not the other and both can see the same (I did a test to check this and yes, I got this problem)

is there any way to do this? thanks

Comment: The only way to bind a user to a specific bean is to use a `@Stateful` bean, which can also keeps client state. See the famous example of shopping cart. If instead you are using @Stateless, the application server keeps a bunch of beans in a pool, and may reuse for several client for performance/scalabilty reason. There's no way to guarantee that a bean will serve a client only.

Comment: so if I change my ejb's to stateful should do the trick? im kinda new to ejb's and I can see that this should work but is there any configuration apart from just changing @Stateless to @Stateful?, im gonna try this one so every time I do a lookup, the think that disturb me the most is that in this situation the session is on 1 server and ejb's are on another (because they want view/session in 1 server and all the data and process in another) i´ll try some magic here using stateless, thanks